# How to quote() non-standard expressions, e.g. 2A-2B?

Tags: r, igraph, nse

Or any other non-parseble expression as in `igraph::graph_from_literal(1A +--+ 1B)`.

Function call `quote(1A-2B)` gives `Error: unexpected symbol in quote(1A"`.

How to get a result similar to

- quote(A-B),
- quote(1-1)?

Comment: As in many programming languages, a symbol in R cannot start with a number. `1A` is not a valid R symbol, and you can't `quote` a syntactically invalid expression. Can I ask what you are trying to achieve here? There will probably be a work-around, but we need some context to help.

Comment: The fragment of code from igraph gives the same error, unless you make the expression into a string: `igraph::graph_from_literal("1A +--+ 1B")`

Comment: But the code `igraph::graph_from_literal(1A +--+ 1B)` just results in an unexpected symbol error

Comment: No, this is not a bug in igraph. You cannot have the symbol `1A` in R unless it is wrapped in quotation marks. See my explanation below. You cannot have "non-standard expressions" like this _anywhere_ unless they are wrapped in quotation marks. The R parser will not allow them. Could you please add some context to explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you trying to create a variable whose name is 1A-1B?  To do that surround it with backquotes ` ``1A-1B`` ` .

Comment: In case of `igraph` the solution is to quote the illegal objects: 
 `igraph::graph_from_literal("1A" +--+ "1B")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote `2A +-+ 2B` as `quote("2A" +-+ "2B")`.
When an expression in `quote(expr)` contains non parsible object names, quote it.

Examples.

```
A2   <- 1       ## creates object "A2" with value `[1] 1`.
2A   <- 1       ## fails because "2A" is a not syntactically valid R expression.
"2A" <- 1       ## creates object "2A" with value `[1] 1`.
assign("2B", 1) ## creates object "2B" with value `[1] 1`.
if (require(igraph)) g <- graph_from_literal("1A" - "2A")
A2; get("2A"); get("2B")
ls()
## [1] "2A" "2B" "A2"
```

Answer (score 5):

As in many programming languages, a *symbol* (i.e. a variable name) in R cannot start with a number. Since `1A` is not a valid R symbol, the expression `1A - 2B` is not syntactically valid. Because `quote` will parse but not execute an expression, you cannot use expressions containing invalid symbols like `1A` or `2B` inside `quote`.

It is difficult to know what you are trying to achieve here, but it seems likely you want to use the quoted expression in a plot. If this is the case, you can use `quote(1*A - 2*B)`, since this *is* a valid expression and the `*` symbols will be removed at plotting.

```r
my_quote <- quote(1*A - 2*B)

plot.new()
text(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, label = my_quote, cex = 6)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-12-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Consider for example path expressions in igraph,
In igraph `g2a <- make_graph(c("1A", "2B"))`  is valid, but  `g2b <- make_graph(~ A1-B2)` is not.

Comment: But these are _strings_, not symbols. If you wrap the symbol in quotation marks, then you can have anything inside the quotes - you don't need syntactically valid expressions inside a string.